# How would you design a function that attaches children of a Component class to an Object class if the components can hold different data?

Tags: c++, oop

In my program, I have an `Object` class to which we can attach components that all derive from a base `Component` class. Since a component can have data that are initialized through it's constructor, when we call `Object::addComponent()` we need to pass the data for this particular component

```
#include <vector>

class Component;
class Object
{
public:
    Object() {}
    /* The challenge comes from implementing this function, the signature will change later in this post 
       and ideally it would return the added component */
    void addComponent();
private:
    std::vector<Component*> m_components;  
};
    
class Component
{
public:
    Component(Object* owner) : m_owner(owner) {}
    // Note the pure virtual destructor, meaning Component is meant to be derived
    virtual ~Component() = 0;
private:
    Object* m_owner;
};
```

Here are two `Component` derived classes for our example

```
// This component holds an int
class ComponentDerivedA : public Component
{
public:
    ComponentDerivedA(Object* owner, int data) : Component(owner), m_data(data) {}
    virtual ~ComponentDerivedA() override {}
private:
    int m_data;
};

// This component holds a string
class ComponentDerivedB : public Component
{
public:
    ComponentDerivedB(Object* owner, char* message) : Component(owner), m_message(message) {}
    virtual ~ComponentDerivedB() override {}
private:
    char* message;
};
```

The only solution I came for to implement the `addComponent()` function the way I want to is to create an enum and a struct:

```
enum class ComponentType { A, B };
struct ComponentInfo
{
    ComponentType type;
    int data;
    char* message
};
```

So we change the signature for `Object::addComponent()` to the following

```
void* Object::addComponent(const ComponentInfo& info);
```

And here is a possible implementation

```
void* Object::addComponent(const ComponentInfo& info)
{
    switch(info.type)
    {
    case A:
    {
        // We ignore cleaning up for this example but it would go in the destructor
        ComponentDerivedA* a = new ComponentDerivedA(this, info.data);
        m_components.push_back(a);
        return a;
    }
    break;

    case B:
    {
        // We ignore cleaning up for this example but it would go in the destructor
        ComponentDerivedB* b = new ComponentDerivedB(this, info.message);
        m_components.push_back(b);
        return b;
    }
    break;
    }
}
```

And here is how we would use it

```
int main()
{
    Object obj;
    
    ComponentInfo info{0};
    info.type = ComponentType::A;
    info.data = 5;
    
    obj.addComponent(info);        

    /*

    If I wanted to use the component right after I would have to do:
    reinterpret_cast<ComponentDerivedA>(obj.addComponent(info)).doSomething();

    */

    return 0;
}
```

This solution works okay but anytime you want to call `addComponent()` you have to declare a struct before, the only benefit is if you add multiple components you can reuse the same struct and just change the data between each call, also is if you add a new component type you have to expand the enum and the function, if you have many component the switch can become very large but the code inside it remains pretty repetitive and simple. And the final flaw is that it's up to the caller to cast the return value as the component type.

Comment: `addComponent` can be made into a template function that adds a pointer to the base type and returns a pointer/reference to the derived type. The question is, how do you specify which type you want? Is `addComponent<ComponentDerivedA>()` acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/T98bqa) is a possible solution.

Note the use of `std::unique_ptr` instead of regular c-pointers.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Component{};

class Object {
public:
    Object() {}
    
    template <typename TDerivedComponent, typename... TArgs>
    TDerivedComponent * addComponent(TArgs&&... args){
        auto ptr = std::make_unique<TDerivedComponent>
            (std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
        TDerivedComponent * result = ptr.get();
        m_components.push_back(std::move(ptr));
        return result;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component> > m_components;  
};

struct ComponentA : public Component {
    ComponentA(int x, int y){}
};
struct ComponentB : public Component {};

struct Invalid{};

int main(){
    Object obj;
    ComponentA * a = obj.addComponent<ComponentA>(1, 2);
    ComponentB * b = obj.addComponent<ComponentB>();
    // obj.addComponent<Invalid>(); -> error!

}
```

Comment: Looks like a nice solution, what happens if I pass more data than required, or if I pass let's say an std::string instead of an int ?

Comment: `std::make_unique<TDerivedComponent>(...)` forwards the arguments to the best-matching constructor of `TDerivedComponent`. If no contructor matches the arguments you get a compilation error.
The type `TArgs&&` is called a [forwarding reference](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c), and it works with just about any types of arguments (`initializer_list` may be problematic).

Comment: @Matt By the way, you should familiarize youself with https://godbolt.org/. See link in the first word of my answer. You can change the code there however you want (e.g. replace one of the `int`s with an `std::string`) and see how it affects the result.

Comment: Great then this is exactly the type of design I was aiming for

Answer (score 0):

You actually can store a derived object into a baseclass object pointer which u already have declared as in the vector.
To make your derived objects also call the correct methods you have to declare the method as virtual inside the base class.
your addComponent() function can then take the pointer of the baseClass

```
addComponent(Component * c)
```

with that signature it can also take derived object pointers.
You should read about static vs dynamic binding in C++.

Comment: This would work but I would prefer delegating component instanciation to the Object class

Comment: I would not recommend that. Objects should not be responsible for creating their dependencies. Dependency Injection is the keyword here.

Comment: "Objects should not be responsible for creating their dependencies" why ? and why would it be a bad thing ?
I've looked up Dependency Injection and it seems to be overly complicated for what I am doing